# One to many relation with multiple ids check in related object

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to ask if there is an option to perform multiple check when `joining table`. The thing is I have the table 'conversations' which has many 'recipients' and I would like to query `database` that way so I know if there is a conversation which has all of the provided recipients so for example I'd like to check if there is a conversation which has `user_id=3` and `user_id=5` at the same time, but I don't want the ones which have only one of this users.

Comment: I think you're after psychicSQL

Comment: What is special about user_id=3 and user_id=5 that you need to confirm both active at the same time?

Comment: @RyanVincent I want to find the conversation between this two specific users. Like when I want to add a message I have to know to which conversation should I add it as conversations are meant to have only two users by now so there will be only two 'participants' linked to specific conversation.

Comment: why do you need to `join` `recipients` when you just need to filter against `user_id` which already exist in the `conversation` table?

Comment: @Fabricator There is no `user_id` field in `conversations` table as it would be a bit pointless :) The thing is I can just get all conversations for one user and then iterate over each to check if it contains also a second user, but I was curious if there is an effective way to do it with just MySQL.

Comment: can you show the 2 table's schema and how they should be joined?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can do this is with a subquery.  Note I haven't verified this query. Also, this presumes that you only have one relation per unique recipient.  If it's possible for a recipient to receive multiple copies of a conversation, then you'll need to count the distinct ids in the subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM conversations
WHERE  1 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recipients 
             WHERE recipients.conversation_id = conversations.id 
                    AND recipients.user_id IN (3, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this kind of search. Use `GROUP CONCAT` to group users of the same conversation together, then use `FIND_IN_SET` to get only conversations that both 3 and 5 are in.

```
select cid, group_concat(user_id) user_ids
from conversations a
group by a.cid
having find_in_set(3, user_ids) and find_in_set(5, user_ids);
```

`cid` is short for `conversation_id`

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8e72/1)